# Android aws SDK :AndroidRuntime(587): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: android, amazon-web-services, amazon-simpledb

I am trying to use AWS Simple DB with androidSdk 1.3.3,and here is my Connection Code

```
AWSCredentials credits = new BasicAWSCredentials("apkey","secretkey");
AmazonSimpleDBClient client = new AmazonSimpleDBClient(credits);
```

I added the necessary Jar ,but i get an exception that points to AwsCredentials and my logcat says

```
E/AndroidRuntime(587): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.amazonaws.auth.BasicAWSCredentials
```

Could i please know where i am wrong ?

LogCat Report:

```
08-16 17:33:04.484: E/AndroidRuntime(587): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-16 17:33:04.484: E/AndroidRuntime(587): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.amazonaws.auth.BasicAWSCredentials
08-16 17:33:04.484: E/AndroidRuntime(587):  at com.Ews.EwsActivity.<init>(EwsActivity.java:24)
08-16 17:33:04.484: E/AndroidRuntime(587):  at java.lang.Class.newInstanceImpl(Native Method)
08-16 17:33:04.484: E/AndroidRuntime(587):  at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1319)
08-16 17:33:04.484: E/AndroidRuntime(587):  at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1023)
08-16 17:33:04.484: E/AndroidRuntime(587):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1871)
08-16 17:33:04.484: E/AndroidRuntime(587):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1981)
08-16 17:33:04.484: E/AndroidRuntime(587):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:123)
08-16 17:33:04.484: E/AndroidRuntime(587):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1147)
08-16 17:33:04.484: E/AndroidRuntime(587):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
08-16 17:33:04.484: E/AndroidRuntime(587):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
08-16 17:33:04.484: E/AndroidRuntime(587):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
08-16 17:33:04.484: E/AndroidRuntime(587):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-16 17:33:04.484: E/AndroidRuntime(587):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
08-16 17:33:04.484: E/AndroidRuntime(587):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
08-16 17:33:04.484: E/AndroidRuntime(587):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
08-16 17:33:04.484: E/AndroidRuntime(587):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: try to put this jars to "libs" folder of the project ...

Comment: I think you had the problem like in below link,

< http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11431552/classnotfoundexception-when-trying-to-access-a-view-in-a-library-project/11431719#11431719 >

Comment: @Selvin yes i did put the Jars in "libs" folder of my project

Comment: @Venkatesh tried like you had mentioned ,does not works!

Comment: Ok. Did you try clean your project by project->clean

Comment: @Venkatesh yes i did clean it  shows error at this point AWSCredentials credits=new BasicAWSCredentials("apkey","secretkey"); !